# T-SQL Combine Multiple Rows Into Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I have this T-SQL (simplified):

```
select 3.00 as score1, null as score2, null as score3, null as score4
union all
select null as score1, 4.5 as score2, 1.5 as score3, null as score4
```

Which produces this:

```
score1  score2  score3  score4
------------------------------
3.00    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    4.5     1.5     NULL
```

But i want to join it into one row, like this:

```
score1  score2  score3  score4
------------------------------
3.00    4.5     1.5     NULL
```

Sorry - im drawing blank (it's late in the day).

Do i need a temporary table?

The reason i'm doing this is that i have the following association:

**Reviews 1..* Scores**

So a regular join produces 1 row for each Score - but i want to insert a record (into another table), that has a column for each record - if you know what i mean:

```
INSERT INTO OtherTable (ReviewId, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4)
????
```

Hope that makes sense.

**EDIT**

Based on @OMG Ponies answer (which he just removed), i came up with this:

```
SELECT CASE MAX(x.score1) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(x.score1) END AS score4
       CASE MAX(x.score2) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(x.score2) END AS score4
       CASE MAX(x.score3) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(x.score3) END AS score4
       CASE MAX(x.score4) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(x.score4) END AS score4
  FROM (select 3.00 as score1, 0 as score2, 0 as score3, 0 as score4
        union all
        select 0 as score1, 4.5 as score2, 1.5 as score3, 0 as score4) x
```

But it's pretty ugly. Any other ideas?

Comment: That's weird, cuz I thought MAX supported returning NULL so it shouldn't have needed the CASE :/

Comment: yeah worst case, i have a solution above. but as i said it's really ugly. i need to insert NULL (not 0), which i why i need the crappy case. eck. what's more i'll need ISNULL's in the subject (in reality) to convert NULL to 0, then convert that back to NULL again for the insert, lol. painful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with my original query (thanks to @OMG Ponies for putting me on the right track):

```
SELECT CASE MAX(x.score1) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(x.score1) END AS score4
       CASE MAX(x.score2) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(x.score2) END AS score4
       CASE MAX(x.score3) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(x.score3) END AS score4
       CASE MAX(x.score4) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(x.score4) END AS score4
  FROM (select 3.00 as score1, 0 as score2, 0 as score3, 0 as score4
        union all
        select 0 as score1, 4.5 as score2, 1.5 as score3, 0 as score4) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Under assumption that only one of both rows has a value in score1, score2, ... Otherwise rewrite your query using the `NULLIF` function.

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(ISNULL(NULLIF(x.score1, 0), y.score1), 0) score1,
    NULLIF(ISNULL(NULLIF(x.score2, 0), y.score2), 0) score2,
    NULLIF(ISNULL(NULLIF(x.score3, 0), y.score3), 0) score3,
    NULLIF(ISNULL(NULLIF(x.score4, 0), y.score4), 0) score4
FROM (SELECT 3.00 AS score1, 0 AS score2, 0 AS score3, 0 AS score4) x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS score1, 4.5 AS score2, 1.5 AS score3, 0 AS score4) y
```

Comment: Yup - that works too - but not much different from the edit in my question, only difference is NULLIF instead of CASE. Is there any other differences?

Answer (score 0):

When I try it (SQL 2008) using a simple `MAX()` it seems to work:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(score1),
    MAX(score2),
    MAX(score3),
    MAX(score4)
FROM
    (select 3.00 as score1, null as score2, null as score3, null as score4 
    union all 
    select null as score1, 4.5 as score2, 1.5 as score3, null as score4) s
```

I ran this test

```
declare @t table (i int null)
insert @t values (null)
insert @t values (1)
select MAX(i) from @t
```

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Not really. I need to end up with what i have in the question above - a single row, with 4 columns. those 4 columns are aggregated from 4 different rows. Unless im misunderstanding your answer...(i very well could be, it's 6pm)

Comment: I'd just edited to clarify - I'm really just wrapping your current query with some MAX functions.

Answer (score 0):

The @OMG Ponies/RPM1984 query seems to work:

```
SELECT MAX(x.score1),
       MAX(x.score2),
       MAX(x.score3),
       MAX(x.score4)
  FROM (select 3.00 as score1, null as score2, null as score3, CAST(null as int) as score4
        union all
        select null as score1, 4.5 as score2, 1.5 as score3, null as score4) x
```

Which results in:

```
3.00    4.5 1.5 NULL
```

I'm not sure what you'd do if multiple rows define the same score.

---

I have to add CAST(null as int) to the fourth column, because otherwise there's no way for SQL Server to work out the type of the fourth column - all it has are two nulls, and nulls can be of any type.

Comment: Yeah i don't have to worry about multiple rows with the same score. For a given field (e.g Score1), out of all the rows (could be 0-10), only one will have the score, all others will be null. I'm surprised `CAST(null as int)` actually works. why in your answer do you have `CAST(null as int)` in the first select, but `null as score4` in the second select?

Comment: @RPM1984 - I *think* I only really needed to do the cast on the null for score4 - otherwise, there's no way for SQL Server to work out what the data type is for the fourth column. But with a real working table, you wouldn't have to give SQL Server this information - it would get it from the column definition.