# T-SQL Multiple Rows to a Single Row

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data similar to the below

```
    Set        Cost        Times
    ----------------------------
    GHT        100         20
    GHA        80          30
    GHE        70          10
```

Sometimes there are more rows, sometimes there are less. What I would like pulled back, using the example above, is something like:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3     Col4     Col5      Col6     Col7     Col8     Col9
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
GHT      100      20       GHA      80        30       GHE      70       10
```

Thanks in advance

JJ

Comment: are the "set" values allways the three that you show here?  are they a know number? do they repeat? is your desired output allways only one row?

Comment: A single query will always return a *fixed* number of columns, and those columns will always have the same names and data types. Although you can use dynamic SQL to construct a different query on the fly, you need to ask yourself why you're performing essentially formatting functions down in the database.

Comment: Luis - there might be less, there might be more. There are a total of 6 possible values. Always one row.

Damien - this table is currently being used in a Pivot Table within excel and I'm putting it on the web. Just thought having a single row would make life easier for me.

Comment: Your choice - you can write some truly horrible SQL to generate the dynamic SQL, or you can do the pivot inside whatever code you're writing to "put it on the web". The latter is usually easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL Combine Multiple Rows Into Single Row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457914/t-sql-combine-multiple-rows-into-single-row)

Comment: @JanuszJasinski what if you have 50 rows in the original set of data, do you want to display 150 columns?

Comment: Actually, Pivot Tables generally want relational-type data too (tabular, fixed columns with fixed meanings).  They don't work very well with variable-column definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are going to have an unknown number of rows that will be returned, you will need to implement dynamic SQL to get the result.  You will also need to both unpivot the 3 columns and then apply the PIVOT to transform the rows back into columns, so it will be a two-step process.

Since you care using SQL Server 2005+, you can use CROSS APPLY to unpivot the data, you will notice that I also use `row_number()` so the rows of data are still grouped together when turned back into the columns.  The code to UNPIVOT the data will be similar to:

```
select col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(50)) col,
  value
from
(
  select [set] as st, cost, times,
    row_number() over(order by (select 1)) rn
  from yourtable
) d
cross apply
(
  values 
   ('set', st), 
   ('cost', cast(cost as varchar(50))),
   ('times', cast(times as varchar(50)))
) c (col, value);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c67bf/10). This will turn the data into the format:

```
|     COL | VALUE |
-------------------
|   set_1 |   GHT |
|  cost_1 |   100 |
| times_1 |    20 |
```

Once the data is in the multiple rows, you can apply the PIVOT.  The dynamic SQL code will be similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(50))) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) rn
                      from yourtable
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'set', 1 union all
                      select 'cost', 2 union all
                      select 'times', 3
                    ) c (col, so)   
                    group by col, rn, so
                    order by rn, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select col+''_''+cast(rn as varchar(50)) col,
                value
              from
              (
                select [set], cost, times,
                  row_number() over(order by (select 1)) rn
                from yourtable
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                values 
                  (''set'', [set]), 
                  (''cost'', cast(cost as varchar(50))),
                  (''times'', cast(times as varchar(50)))
              ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c67bf/11). This gives a result:

```
| SET_1 | COST_1 | TIMES_1 | SET_2 | COST_2 | TIMES_2 | SET_3 | COST_3 | TIMES_3 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   GHT |    100 |      20 |   GHA |     80 |      30 |   GHE |     70 |      10 |
```